# Inserting print into a table

Tags: printing, lua, lua-table

I am currently trying to use `table.insert` to insert `print` into a table my code is below:

```
local myTable = {}
table.insert(myTable, print("hi"))
```

Comment: You should create another function `function print_hi() print"hi" end` and insert it into your table `table.insert(yourTable, print_hi)`

Comment: Is there a way to run it from the table as well?

Comment: What are problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Im just trying to print from a table using insert instead of the method where you do table.insert(table, "text") then print it out

Comment: @NicholasJohnson - To run it: `yourTable[1]()`

Answer (score 0):

assume:

```
local myTable = {}
```

*Case 1*

to insert a `function` into `myTable`:

```
table.insert(myTable, print)
```

to execute a `function` inserted into `myTable`:

```
myTable[1]("hi") --just as an ordinary print
```

*Case 2 *

to insert a `function` into `myTable` with an argument assigned:

```
table.insert(myTable, function() print("hi") end)
```

to execute a `function` inserted into `myTable`:

```
myTable[1]()
```